# Cannot download and install scikit-learn

Tags: python, installation, scikit-learn

I am pretty new to python. I want to use KMean code, and I want to install `scikit-learn` or `sklearn`.

I used this code to attempt install these packages:

```
pip install -U sklearn
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

But I got this error:

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_reihaneh/sklearn/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-89YQB7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_reihaneh/sklearn
Storing debug log for failure in /home/reihaneh/.pip/pip.log
```

What is the  cause of the problem?

Comment: I use linux (ubuntu)

Comment: I have got so many debugging errors, although I have numpy and scipy installed. when we use [pip install scikits.learn], It is using the version 0.8 and by default when u try to re attempt installing scikits.learn 0.8 version is being picked up by the system. So using [pip install -U scikits.learn] will upgrade the version of scikits,learn and installs successfully in the system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`pip install -U <package>`, short for `pip install --upgrade <package>`, will upgrade `<package>` to the most recent stable version in the pip repo.

`pip install <package>` will install the most recent stable version of `<package>` in the pip repo.

The difference is upgrading vs. installing. You want the latter.

`scikit-learn` requires `scipy` and `numpy`, so here are the commands you should issue:

```
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
pip install scikit-learn
```

If you already have any of the dependencies, just plug in a `-U` between `pip install` and the package name.

If you're using Python 3.x, replace `pip` with `pip3`.

Comment: thank you very much dear Erip, I had already numpy (to check it, I used import numpy as np; and it worked). Also I had scipy. but still got error when I use: pip install scikit-learn     Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_reihaneh/scikit-learn/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-qwSIR2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_reihaneh/scikit-learn

Comment: @user3511520 What version of Ubuntu are you running? 14.04? It seems like you want to install scikit-learn for the global, system-wide Python installation. Have you tried `sudo pip install scikit-learn` (or `sudo pip install -U scikit-learn`)? Another option is to try installing from the git repo directly: `sudo pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git`. (As @erip said, replace `pip` with `pip3` if you're using Python 3.)

Comment: @user3511520 Optionally, you might also try installing [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It's a very nice package manager for data science, scientific computing, and etc. tools. It also enables you to more easily switch between Python2 and Python3 with installed packages.

Comment: @user3511520 No problem. Do note, if you wish to install a package only for a certain project, you should use [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Yes, @MichaelRecachinas is 100% right - you shouldn't need to use `sudo` because you should be doing all of this within a `virtualenv`.

Comment: This solution works on `pipenv`.

Answer (score 0):

pip install scikit-learn

it solved my problem.

Comment: Reading the original question, it appears that they've already tried these commands.

Answer (score -1):

majority of machine learning libraries does not support python 32 bit,
so solution is to shift to 64 bit python

Comment: The question doesn't mention anything about 32- or 64-bit. Please read [answer]. In particular, please make sure that the answers you post address the question being asked.